# How to fix location=0 at python curve fit scipy.optimize

Tags: python, curve-fitting

Here are the sample codes

```
x=[1.5,4,10,50,90]
y=[6/100,2.6/100,1.4/100,0.4/100,0.2/100]

def f(x, a, loc,scale):
    loc=0 
    return gamma.pdf(x, a, loc, scale)
optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y)
```

The results are giving me a loc=1. Is there any way that I can make loc=0?
I noticed that, when x does not have integer elements, the loc can not be fixed at 0, otherwise the curve fit does not work. May I know the algorithm behind that?

---

As an example to show why mine code did not work in some cases,

```py
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.stats import gamma

def f(x, a, loc,scale):
    loc=0 
    return gamma.pdf(x, a, loc, scale)

init_guess=[0.1,0,0.1]

fig= plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
fit_2worst = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y,p0=init_guess)

x2 = np.linspace (0, 100, 200)
y2 = gamma.pdf(x2, a=fit_2worst[0][0], loc=fit_2worst[0][1],scale=fit_2worst[0][2])

plt.title('Gamma with k='+str("{:.2}".format(fit_2worst[0][0]))+'\nTheta='+str(int(fit_2worst[0][2])))
plt.plot(x2, y2, "y-") 
print ('k:',fit_2worst[0][0],'location:',fit_2worst[0][1],'theta:',fit_2worst[0][2])
plt.show()
```

Returns are

`k: 36.171512499294444 location: 0.0 theta: 3.725335489050758`

The shown picture is
[image]

With the code proposed by @Joe, I am able to get the correct one

```py
def f(x, a, scale):
    #loc=0 
    return gamma.pdf(x, a, scale=scale, loc=0)

fig= plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
opt = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y)


x2 = np.linspace (0, 100, 200)
y2 = gamma.pdf(x2, a=opt[0][0],scale=opt[0][1])

plt.title('Gamma with k='+str("{:.2}".format(opt[0][0]))+'\nTheta='+str(int(opt[0][1])))
plt.plot(x2, y2, "y-") 
print ('k:',opt[0][0],'location:',0,'theta:',opt[0][1])
plt.show()
```

With a return 
`k: 0.23311781831847955 location: 0 theta: 132.0300661365553`

[image]

I am not sure why the previous codes do not work for floats but integers?

Comment: Answer myself, according to @Joe, I should not include loc in the `f` function as a variable, which would be estimated by the optimize.curve_fit function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just least squares.

You can make loc = 0 by not making it variable and so not free for the optimizer to use. Try

```
def f(x, a, scale):
    #loc=0 
    return gamma.pdf(x, a, scale=scale, loc=0)

optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y)
```

With image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.stats import gamma

import numpy as np
x=[1.5,4,10,50,90]
y=[6/100,2.6/100,1.4/100,0.4/100,0.2/100]

def f(x, a, scale):
    #loc=0 
    return gamma.pdf(x, a, scale=scale, loc=0)

opt = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y)
print(opt)

x_0 = np.arange(0.0, 90)
y_0 = f(x_0, *(opt[0]))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x_0,y_0, 'r.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Got an error    `File "<ipython-input-13-4964363ec835>", line 9
    return gamma.pdf(x,a,loc=0,scale)
                              ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

Comment: Fixed. Flip loc=0 and scale

Comment: this is awesome. I was not able to do this because I included loc as a variable before

Comment: But what you did is also a valid solution in some cases. It basically allows the optimizer to shift the pdf to find the best fit.

Comment: Thanks for the information for this clarification, I observed that it works for integers of the real data points, not for floating numbers, any explanation?

Comment: Don't unterstand what you mean. Please post images of the fit.

Comment: I just edited my question to show a case my precious code fails. It could work for integers, but not for the floats. There is a 1.5 in x, and it failed in my codes.